# Display Messages notifications inside a div box

Tags: html, css, django

When the user enter a not valid credentials it print this notificaitons message:

`Sorry, your password was incorrect.<br/> Please double-check your password`

But this doesn't look good when it is printed:
[image]

I want it to be printed between the Login button and the Forgot password.
Like that:
[image]

So theoretically the white box should expend to the bootom to leave so place for the notifications message

html file

```
<div class="testlol2" >
    <div class="login-box" align="center">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'images/testlogo.png' %}" alt="">
    <div class="testlol" align="center">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="my-button">
            <input class="login-button" type="submit" value="Log in">
        </div>
    </form>
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <p{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message  }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <a class="forgot" href="">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css file

```
body{
    background-color: #fafafa !important;
}

.messages {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 8px;
  color: red;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 28px;
  left: 134px;
  width: 200px;
}


.testlol {
  position: relative;
  top: 115px;
  right: 90px;
}

.testlol2 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.login-box {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin:0 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 280px;
  width: 325px;
}

.forgot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 128px;
  right: 95px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 14px!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: did you try with `<li>` instead of `<p>`? Also `.forgot` shouldn't be absolute so it will be pushed down.

Comment: @ITgoldman Just tried it, it does the same thing

Comment: try `<li>` instead of `<p>` and also I don't think `.messages`  in CSS file should be __relative__.

Comment: @IjazUrRahim Tried ```<li>``` and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (css) is quite a mess. I tried making some **minimal** changes to it would partly look ok. Main fix was to make the `.messages` have margin of 115px from top rather than be positioned 115px from top, so that login-box would expand in height.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fafafa !important;
}

.messages {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 8px;
  color: red;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 28px;
  left: 134px;
  width: 200px;
}

.testlol {
  position:relative;
  right: 90px;
  margin-top: 115px;
}

.testlol2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.login-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  /* height: 280px; */
  width: 325px;
}

.forgot {
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 128px;
  right: 95px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 14px!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="testlol2">
  <div class="login-box" align="center">
    <img class="logo" src="{% static 'images/testlogo.png' %}" alt="">
    <div class="testlol" align="center">
      <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="my-button">
          <input class="login-button" type="submit" value="Log in">
        </div>
      </form>
      {% if messages %}
      <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <p{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}

      <a class="forgot" href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok interesting, didn't know about that I needed to use a margin-top for that. Thanks you

Comment: or `padding-top`